# How to control VPN client via commandline

Tags: networking, command-line, osx-snow-leopard, vpn

There must be a way to control the built-in VPN client in OS-X Snow Leopard, I simply can't find documentation about it. I want to be able to connect and disconnect while I'm ssh'd into my box remotely. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save the following AppleScript to gfw.scpt

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current location of network preferences
        set VPNservice to service "The Great Fire Wall" -- name of the VPN service
        if exists VPNservice then connect VPNservice
        set isConnected to connected of current configuration of VPNservice
        if isConnected then
            --- do something or nothing
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

use  ***osascript gfw.scpt*** to start it from terminal.

Comment: Gotta love AppleScript... so verbose. :(

Comment: I'm using this in Terminal.app which works ok.
Does it work for you via ssh?

Comment: No: `startIntelix.scpt:50:58: script error: Expected end of line but found identifier. (-2741)`